# Teleportation Area is not working even when valid

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, xri

***-"fixed" this problem by using the SteamVR Plugin and modifying it to my needs***

I am just learning Unity for VR Use and followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxMzAw2Sg5w&ab_channel=JustinPBarnett) tutorial to set up a basic scene. However, even when following the tutorial closely, the teleportation system just doesn't work. Nothing happens when I point at an area that should be valid (and looks like it is, because the lasers are white) when pressing any button or trigger on the controller.

Here are my settings and other Infos:

- Unity 2021.3.4f1
- XR Interaction Toolkit Version 2.02
- Set up OpenXR in the XR Plug-in Management
- Added a teleportation area script to the plane
- Teleportation Provider is turned on
- In the XR Ray Interactor Settings of the Controllers the Interaction Layer Mask and Raycast Mask is set to the Layer, that the teleportation plane is in (actually "Everything")
- The XRI Default Input Actions (for RightHand Locomotion same as LeftHand Locomotion) looks like this:
  [Teleport Select and Mode Activate on Primary2DAcis, Teleport Mode Cancel on gripPressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGbDw.png)

I think that's all the info I can give but don't hesitate to ask for more.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hey, I seem to have similar issue while going through the Create with VR tutorial on https://learn.unity.com/. For me it only works when I use On Select Exited but not on Activate or Deactivate, which I want. That being said, I think the teleport settings in the Input Systems that you have screenshot are not the buttons is not what you need anyway. I think you need look under Select and Activate. Did you make any progress so far on this issue?

Comment: Not even sure if I am right with Input System on second thought.

Comment: @JAQuent Hey, sorry for the late answer. I didn't really find an answer for the problem, even in another Unity Discord. My solution was quite simple, I just used the SteamVR Plugin for Unity... That worked quite well for me and I just modified it to my needs... Hope that helps! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I scrapped that project and started a new one and all the XR-BUGS were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the `Locomotion System` object disabled in hierarchy by default and enabled by script. Having it enabled in hierarchy by default fixed the problem.